# Binding Script to Radio Buttons : Weird Behaviour : Not Binding by Name

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

In my mvc application im binding the same function to both of these radio buttons.

```
$('#Fra').bind('change', function () {
    f_GC();
});

$('#Hea').bind('change', function () {
    f_GC();        
});
```

The way these few lines worked was that Fra had 2 radio buttons ( different values ) with the same Name/ ID. And Hea had 4 radio buttons ( different values ) with the same Name / ID...

*My Understanding was that all ID's that fall under Fra, / Hea would bind to the functions...*

These worked for the longest time and i must have changed some code.... however to get all 6 radio buttons to run these functions i must now bind them like this ..

```
$('input:radio[name=Fra][value=' + 1 + ']').bind('change', function () {
    f_GC();  
});
$('input:radio[name=Fra][value=' + 2 + ']').bind('change', function () {
    f_GC();  
});
$('input:radio[name=Hea][value=' + 1 + ']').bind('change', function () {
    f_GC();  
});
$('input:radio[name=Hea][value=' + 2 + ']').bind('change', function () {
    f_GC();  
});
$('input:radio[name=Hea][value=' + 3 + ']').bind('change', function () {
    f_GC();  
});
$('input:radio[name=Hea][value=' + 4 + ']').bind('change', function () {
    f_GC();  
});
```

**Is there a simple explanation for this behavior?** *The chrome debugging tools show no JS Errors in either of the 2 configs.*

Comment: An ID should be unique in your view, what about using classes instead ? `$('.Fra').bind('change', function () { f_GC(); });`

Comment: No two elements can have the same ID in a document, so I'd suggest you change the IDs of your buttons. Also, bind is no longer the preferred method, you can use on() instead.

Comment: Thanks guys, Im typing to fast, i don't use the same ID thoughout all my controls, Thanks for the hint with "on", ill look into that. I don't think i would want to have to go through my huge view and add all radios to a class, maybe we can use the same Name on all of the radio buttons?

Comment: @MartinVézina Of course two elements can have the same ID, but this is not really a best practice in my opinion.

Comment: From w3c : The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree. When a node is in a Document, its home subtree is that Document's tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating all your fields by the name is simple.

```
$('input:radio[name=Hea]').on('change', function () {
    f_GC();
});
```

There is probably many different ways to do it , but this one will work :)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery doc says about ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/):
"Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM."

If you don't want to change the IDs then another solution can be to add the eventlistener to a parent element of the lists and use "delegate" style event attachment. Then in the event handler you can query the id of the element that fired the event and act accordingly.